# New to swift programming and I need help using a feature of an objective C cocoa pod I have implemented

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

First post, I hope this isn't too annoying of a question.The cocoapod is called HNKwordLookup. I know this will probably be an easy task but I need help telling my program to use the picking of a random word function as the instructions on how to use this function is foreign to me as I have no knowledge in objective C (language the pod is written in). I have successfully created a header file for Xcode. If someone could point me towards how and where in a swift based Xcode project to implement the code below I would be very thankful, cheers.

```
 Looking up a random word

[[HNKLookup sharedInstance] randomWordWithCompletion:^(NSString *randomWord, NSError *error) {
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", randomWord);
}
}];
```

Here is the link to the documentation of the pod (https://github.com/hkellaway/HNKWordLookup) as well as the original source of the pod from cocoapods.org (https://cocoapods.org/?q=random%20word)

Comment: Are you not able to use it in your Swift code? Did you tried `HNKLookup.sharedInstance.rando` and use intellisense after that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Podfile has:

> `pod "HNKWordLookup", "~> 1.1"`
>   `pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'`

Assuming your swift project `Bridging-Header.h` has:

> `#import <HNKWordLookup/HNKLookup.h>`

Then all you need to do is:

```
import HNKWordLookup

//...

func doSomething() {

    HNKLookup.sharedInstance().randomWord { (randomWord, error) in
        if let randomWord = randomWord {
            print(randomWord)
        }
        else if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ah rightio thanks for that, Im starting to think I shouldve started learning objective c instead of swift, there just seemed to be so much more resources on the former :/ While I've got you here, would you have any idea on how to provide the API unique key? Working from you're example code above, he doSomething function calls upon HNKLookup, but I have not yet supplied it with my API code from Wordnik. I know I must type 
     
`HNKLookup.sharedInstance(withAPIKey: myAPIKey)`
     

but I just have no idea where to actually put it in the project. thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: @mBlot Nah, it's good you're on Swift. It's growing. Infact there's alot of learning material in Swift now. So much so that you need not worry about even understanding the Objective-C syntax if you're just using the APIs.

Comment: @mBlot Anyways, you can put `HNKLookup.sharedInstance(withAPIKey: myAPIKey)` in `AppDelegate`'s `application(_,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` if you want. Quick and dirty :P

Comment: @mBlot ofcourse do `import HNKWordLookup` in `AppDelegate` too